# How to Persist ArrayList within Spring Entity class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud

I have the following below member variable declaration for Users entity class and have created `UserRepository` for the entity and have autowired the `UserRepository` instance in the controller class.

All was working fine, but when I declared an array-list in my entity class, my controllers crashes.

My question is how can I declare list within entity class and access it through public function in controller.

```
@Entity
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private  ArrayList <String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();

   //Omitted Class Member Functions
    }
```

Following is error trace

```
 - ERROR 3040 --- [           main]
   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful:
   alter table video_courses drop constraint FK_gb79j8mlvu17uvv38mp0x9ts
 - 2014-08-22 11:10:07.210 ERROR 3040 --- [           main]
   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : user lacks privilege or
   object not found: PUBLIC.VIDEO_COURSES
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I missed the  `@ElementCollection` and  `@CollectionTable` annotation in my entity declaration.

```
 @Entity
    public class Users {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            private long id;

            private String name;

            @ElementCollection
            @CollectionTable(name="listOfUsers")
            private  ArrayList <String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();

           //Omitted Class Member Functions
        }
```